# Interactive UI for Synology NAS using DLNA?

Tags: dlna

I've got a synology nas.

I connect to my movie library from TV using DLNA protocol.

there is no connection from NAS to TV..

Nas connect to router.. TV access NAS content via WiFi..

Problem is I only see a listing on the TV.. There is no movie description, not searchable, generally the UI sucks..

I'm wondering how I could get a much friendlier interface using DLNA...

Comment: What TV? What are you connecting to the NAS to show the content? Is it built into the TV or a separate box?

Answer (score 0):

For my Samsung TV I use ArkMC app during half of year, it's stream video , photos to any devices what I want by DLNA , downloaded on Android and heared that it will be in IOS soon also.May be it will help you

good luck!